# Axios get waterfall way

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

I have a JSON like below and need to create a data structure have user's complete profile by fetching the history and personal details from links in JSON. Any thoughts how to I do it using axios?

```
JSON={
      0:{
          userid:"...",
          details:"http:://<user>/profile",
          history:"http://<user>/history"
      }
      1:{
          userid:"...",
          details:"http:://<user>/profile",
          history:"http://<user>/history"
      }
      2:{
          userid:"...",
          details:"http:://<user>/profile",
          history:"http://<user>/history"
      }
    }
```

desired result json is

```
  JSON:{
    0:{
        userid:"1",
        name:"<datafrom profile>",
        age:"<data from profile>",
        last_login:"<data from history>"
    },
    1:{
        userid:"1",
        name:"<datafrom profile>",
        age:"<data from profile>",
        last_login:"<data from history>"
    },
    2:{
        userid:"2",
        name:"<datafrom profile>",
        age:"<data from profile>",
        last_login:"<data from history>"
    },
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the details and history key value pairs are legit urls. I'll use `http://someDataUrl.com` and `http://someHistoryUrl.com` in this example.

Also, not really sure what your endpoints will return so I made up some examples.

```
function getDataInfo(user){
  return axios.get(`http://someDataUrl.com/${user}`)
}

function getHistoryInfo(user){
  return axios.get(`http://someHistoryUrl.com/${user}`)
}

let json = {}
axios.all([getDataInfo(), getHistoryInfo()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (data, history) {
    // use response from each to populate data object literal. Something like this? :
    json.name = data.name
    json.last_login = history.last_login
  }));
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It really gives me a idea. I just updated the problem statement. Would really appreciate your  help

Comment: Seems like you want to map the data from the first example to the second example using a json request?

Comment: yes I need to iteratively fetch the links in first json to create the second json

Comment: think you just need to loop through the data, and then use something similar to the functions i've provided for each index